# Density curve on histogram is flat

Tags: r, histogram, curve

I am trying to plot a curve that follows the trend of the histogram of my data, I have looked around and have tried out other peoples code but I still get a flat line. Here is my code

```
hist(Ferr,xlab = "Ferritin Plasma Concentration", ylab = "Frequency", main = "Histogram of Ferritin 
Plasma Concentration", xlim = c(0,250), ylim = c(0,50), cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.8,cex.main = 1)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(Ferr), sd = sd(Ferr)), col="blue", add=TRUE)
lines(density(Ferr), col="red")
```

If anyone can help me to see where I have gone wrong, that would be great thank you.

Comment: Do your axis limits fit the range of your data?

Comment: A simple way to check would be to remove `xlim = c(0,250), ylim = c(0,50),` and let `hist` set the ranges.

Comment: My data has got the right range and after trying removing the xlim etc, it hasnt affected the line. The line itself still stays flat against the x axis and not following the histogram

Answer (score 2):

Unlike an histogram, the integral of a density function over the whole space is equal to 1 :

```
sum(density(x)*dx) = 1
```

To scale the density function to the histogram, you can multiply it by the maximum value of the histogram bins and divide it by the distance between points.

Let's take `mtcars$mpg` as example:

```
Ferr <- mtcars$mpg
d <- density(Ferr)
dx <- diff(d$x)[1] 

sum(d$y)*dx
[1] 1.000851

h <- hist(Ferr)
lines(x=d$x,y=max(h$counts)*d$y/dx)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `freq = FALSE` (and remove the constraints on `ylim`and `xlim` and change `"Frequency"` to `"Density"`):

```
hist(Ferr,
     freq= FALSE, 
     xlab = "Ferritin Plasma Concentration", ylab = "Density", 
     main = "Histogram of Ferritin Plasma Concentration", 
     cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.8,cex.main = 1)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(Ferr), sd = sd(Ferr)), col="blue", add=TRUE)
lines(density(Ferr), col="red")
```

Toy data:

```
Ferr <-  rnorm(1000)
```

[image]